# How to create column-range chart from data of a HTML table?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to get a column-range chart that shows columns from min and max columns of a HTML table.

I have already built a bar graph (column graph) from the table but am unable to make it work for the column-range graph.

```
$(function() {

  $('#container').highcharts({
    data: {
      table: 'datatable'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      inverted: true
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
    },
    yAxis: {
      allowDecimals: true,
      title: {
        text: 'Mean difference (d)'
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
          this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
      }
    }
  });

});
```

I expect to get a column-graph instead of a bar graph.

This is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/karnan796/1jc0hzdr/4/) of how I want my output to be.

Comment: The JS fiddle is not showing the output, but you can run it on your PC and see the result. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I have update the JSfiddle link @Abhi Patel

Comment: Please post the html data too. Which you are setting as datatable

Comment: Is there any way of adding scatter points showing average on each of these line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below you can find a fully working example with `columnrange` series type and data form `HTML` table:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: true
    },
    data: {
        table: 'datatable'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        columnrange: {
            pointWidth: 5,
        }
    }
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oks6xf7d/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.table

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just did a silly mistake of not including a CDN of HighCharts.